# Access Silverstripe Page Requirements from a controller

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a the following in mysite/code/Page.php:

```
...

class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    Requirements::javascript("themes/example/js/global1.js");
    Requirements::javascript("themes/example/js/global2.js");
    Requirements::javascript("themes/example/js/global3.js");
  }
}

...
```

and then a custom controller in mysite/controllers/PlayController.php:

```
...

class PlayController extends ContentController {

  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    Requirements::javascript("themes/example/js/play.js");
  }
}

...
```

I would like to use the Requirements from Page.php in PlayController.php. Since they both extend `ContentController`, is this possible?

A little background; `PlayController` is used to display a page for a theatre play with the template Layout/PlayPage.ss. If I put the Requirements in templates/Page.ss, they are inherited by PlayPage.ss. But I'd like to put the Requirements in a controller, so I can use Silverstripe's `combine_files` feature. Hope this makes sense!

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a subclass of `ContentController` that can serve as the base-class for both of your controllers. Eg. you create a `MyController extends ContentController` and then `PlayController` and `Page_Controller` extend `MyController`.

*Or* you could just require all the files in both controllers… if that's too much redundancy, you could also use the config API for this. Here's an example:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController 
{
  private static $js_requirements = [
    "themes/example/js/global1.js",
    "themes/example/js/global2.js",
    "themes/example/js/global3.js"
  ];

  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    foreach ($this->config()->js_requirements as $js) {
        Requirements::javascript($js);
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your `PlayController`, you could access the config of `Page_Controller` like so:

```
class PlayController extends ContentController 
{
  public function init() {
    parent::init();
    foreach (Config::inst()->get('Page_Controller', 'js_requirements') as $js) {
        Requirements::javascript($js);
    }
    Requirements::javascript("themes/example/js/play.js");
  }
}
```

You could then also use the YAML config to configure your requirements, eg.:

```
# mysite/_config/config.yml
Page_Controller:
  js_requirements:
    - "themes/example/js/global4.js"
```

**Note:** Always use `dev/build`, so that your config variables are being picked up.